# How can i edit this message box?

Tags: vb.net

How can I edit this MessageBox? Because I want to add a code to the button.

[image]

This is my code. How can I access the message box in the image so I can put a If else condition to the buttons?

```
Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
Dim t As Integer
Dim s As Integer

xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(xlPath)
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Payment Voucher Printing")

xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 3, s + 8) = VOUCHER_NUMBERTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 6, s + 8) = DATE_OF_PAYMENTTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 7, s + 2) = PAID_TOTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 12, s + 8) = AMOUNTTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 12, s + 7) = TOTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 12, s + 6) = FROMTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 12, s + 5) = SALES_OF_INVOICE_NUMBERTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 12, s + 3) = ACTIVITYTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 12, s + 1) = PAYEE_COMPANYTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 17, s + 3) = TYPE_OF_EXPENSETextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 20, s + 3) = ACCOUNT_CODETextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 23, s + 3) = CHECKTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 24, s + 3) = BANKTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 25, s + 3) = DATE1TextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 22, s + 6) = TYPE_OF_SUPPORTING_DOCUMENTTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 23, s + 6) = VATABLETextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 24, s + 6) = SUBJECT_TO_W_TAXTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 25, s + 6) = W_TAX_RATETextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 23, s + 8) = INPUT_VATTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 24, s + 8) = W_TAXTextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 25, s + 8) = BALANCETextBox.Text()
xlWorkSheet.Cells(t + 21, s + 8) = TOTAL_PHPTextBox.Text()

Try
    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(xlPath)
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try

releaseObject(xlApp)
releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

MsgBox("You can find the file C:\Users\Desktop\")
Dim res As MsgBoxResult
res = MsgBox("Process completed, Would you like to open file?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
If (res = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
    Process.Start(xlpath)
End If
```

Comment: You can't edit it. It's part of Excel.  If you want to add custom behaviour then you'd have to check whether the file already exists first and display your own message.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you for your response and for the info.

Comment: But how can I do that without deleting the existed file?

Answer (score 0):

You can control and direct this messagebox in the way you want, but it's a very difficult task
You can do it yourself before you reach this messagebox and check that the file is available. Give the new file name if available

```
        If System.IO.File.Exists(xlPath) = True Then
        xlPath = Application.StartupPath & "\" & NewFilename & ".xlsx"
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already have a solution. I put a msgbox above before SaveAs.